# My custom pagination not displaying

Tags: query, pagination, navigation

I'm testing a custom pagination feature but my pagination is not showing, is there something I forgot to do?

here's my arguments and query inserted in my template:

```
<?php
                        global $wp_query, $wpex_query;
                        if ( $wpex_query ) {
                            $total = $wpex_query->max_num_pages;
                        } else {
                            $total = $wp_query->max_num_pages;
                        }
                        $args = array(
                        'post_type' => 'post',
                        'category_name' => 'templates-wordpress',
                        'post_status'=>'publish', 
                        'numberposts' => -1,
                        'post_status' => null,
                        'post_parent' => null,
                        'posts_per_page' => 6,
                        'paged' => $paged  //very important
                        );
                        $wpex_query = new WP_Query( $args );
                        if ($wpex_query->have_posts()) :
                    ?>
```

And here is my function:

```
if ( !function_exists( 'wpex_pagination' ) ) {

function wpex_pagination() {

    $prev_arrow = is_rtl() ? '→' : '←';
    $next_arrow = is_rtl() ? '←' : '→';

    global $wp_query;
    $total = $wp_query->max_num_pages;
    $big = 999999999; // need an unlikely integer
    if( $total > 1 )  {
         if( !$current_page = get_query_var('paged') )
             $current_page = 1;
         if( get_option('permalink_structure') ) {
             $format = 'page/%#%/';
         } else {
             $format = '&paged=%#%';
         }
        echo paginate_links(array(
            'base'          => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ),
            'format'        => $format,
            'current'       => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
            'total'         => $total,
            'mid_size'      => 3,
            'type'          => 'list',
            'prev_text'     => $prev_arrow,
            'next_text'     => $next_arrow,
         ) );
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You will pass the **$wpex_query** object into **wpex_pagination** function. Currently **$wp_query** object is not getting your custom query details. Here is the updated for wpex_pagination function.

```
if ( !function_exists( 'wpex_pagination' ) ) {
    function wpex_pagination( $new_query ) {

        $prev_arrow = is_rtl() ? '→' : '←';
        $next_arrow = is_rtl() ? '←' : '→';

        global $wp_query;

        $temp_query = $wp_query; // saving old $wp_query object into temp variable
        $wp_query = $new_query; // updating old $wp_query object with $new_query object

        $total = $wp_query->max_num_pages;
        $big = 999999999; // need an unlikely integer
        if( $total > 1 )  {
             if( !$current_page = get_query_var('paged') )
                 $current_page = 1;
             if( get_option('permalink_structure') ) {
                 $format = 'page/%#%/';
             } else {
                 $format = '&paged=%#%';
             }
            echo paginate_links(array(
                'base'          => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ),
                'format'        => $format,
                'current'       => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
                'total'         => $total,
                'mid_size'      => 3,
                'type'          => 'list',
                'prev_text'     => $prev_arrow,
                'next_text'     => $next_arrow,
             ) );
        }

        $wp_query = $temp_query; // revert back to old $wp_query object
        $temp_query = '';
    }
}
```

Now you will call the **wpex_pagination** function like this way `wpex_pagination( $wpex_query )` in your php file

Comment: Hello, your version of the function seems very good, but strangely I still have nothing that appears. And when I inspect the area of ​​the function call with my browser, notthing is displayed

Comment: Is it showing all posts?

Comment: can you remove it **'numberposts' => -1,** from your 1st snippet?

Comment: I deleted "'postsposts' => -1" I still have no change. But I noticed that despite "posts_per_page" => 6 "all my posts have posted (8 in all)